# mysql_real_escape_string() wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Next code send me this error: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in....

What can i do?... i need this code work corectly. Please help me.

```
    if (isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'register')
    {
    $parola_user = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['psw']));
    $email_anunt = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['email']));


   if (email_exists($email))
    {
    $err = "Adressa exist";
    }
      else
    {
    $user_id = wp_insert_user(array(
    'user_pass' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $psw) ,
    'user_login' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_login', $email) ,
    'user_email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email) ,
    'role' => 'author'
    ));
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be passing an object rather than string in `wp_insert_user` function , dump these 2 variables first to see what they contain $psw and $email.

Your key value pairs must not have been scalar , that's why this error is generated.